# Powershell script to get IIS configuration details

Tags: powershell, logging, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I am looking for fairly generic powerhell cdm allowing me to get the information about IIS - which directory is the log being written to and which fields it is logging.

I need to query circa 400 servers in the environment and check for the differences

We use 2008 r2 with IIS 7

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I know IIS has WMI interfaces which are pretty solid.  You'll need to look up the classes though.